# 'cannot find -lboost_iostreams' while trying to install Deluge 1.3.3

Tags: python, deluge

While trying to install deluge 1.3.3 (I need this specific version) I get an error.

I install all the needed packages through

```
sudo apt-get install g++ make python-all-dev python-all python-dbus \
python-gtk2 python-notify librsvg2-common python-xdg python-support \
subversion libboost-dev libboost-python-dev \
libboost-thread-dev libboost-date-time-dev libboost-filesystem-dev \
libssl-dev zlib1g-dev python-setuptools \
python-mako python-twisted-web python-chardet python-simplejson
```

I then build it

```
$ python setup.py build
```

and

```
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

then I get a long list at the end of which there is the error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_iostreams
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Can you help me out with this?

Answer (score 2):

It's trying to build libtorrent and you do not have the buildtools (gcc) installed to do this. I would suggest rather than building libtorrent just install `python-libtorrent`.